# Accessing a Google Sheet via App Engine causes exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets

I have a simple Java app that tries to access a Google sheet, but whenever I run it I get an exception. The code is:

```
public class SheetsIntegration {
private static HttpTransport transport;
private static JacksonFactory jsonFactory;
private static AppEngineDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;
private Sheets service;
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "My App";

private static List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

public SheetsIntegration() {
    try {
        transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = AppEngineDataStoreFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        service = getSheetsService();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}

public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = AccessSheet.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret_access.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, scopes)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
    AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp app = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver());
    Credential credential = app.authorize("user");// This is line 55
    return credential;
}

public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

I get the following exception when I instantiate SheetsIntegration ...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server  at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.demos.SheetsIntegration.authorize(SheetsIntegration.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.demos.SheetsIntegration.getSheetsService(SheetsIntegration.java:60)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.demos.SheetsIntegration.(SheetsIntegration.java:37)

SheetsIntegration.java:55 is where I try to create the Credential object - I added a comment to this line.

In my pom I have the following entry:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
<version>6.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution to my problem, so I shall post here in case anyone else has something similar. In my case I was using 3.1.0 of the servlet-api. Once I downgraded to 2.5, the problem went away (obviously other problems will follow).